# CMake add_custom_command has no effect if output file exists

Tags: cmake

I need to generate a couple of files from txt base file. But if these files already exist, NMake Makefiles generator just omits generation command:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT "FILE.FI" "FILE.h"
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../Tools/GEN.exe
                   DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/FILE.txt"
                   WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

---

**There are no generated files**

Filesystem:

```
FILE.txt
```

build.make

```
...
D:\Path\To\Project\..\..\Tools\GEN.exe 
...
```

---

**Generated files exist**

But if `FILE.FI` and `FILE.h` exist:

Filesystem:

```
FILE.txt
FILE.FI
FILE.h
```

build.make:

```
...
```

So, my question is: How to force CMake update existing files?

**P.S.** I've tried to add

```
file(REMOVE "FILE.FI" "FILE.h")
```

to CMakeLists.txt. It works, but seems like hack.

Comment: If you need this command to run every time you run the build, use `add_custom_target`.

Comment: `add_custom_command` executes given *COMMAND* when an *OUTPUT* file(s) doesn't exist or *OUTPUT* file is **older than** *DEPENDS* file(s). If you don't need "older than" check, then `add_custom_command` is not for you, choose other approaches. E.g. `add_custom_target`, as arrowd suggests.

Comment: If I replace `"FILE.FI"` with `"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/DPSM.FI"` CMake adds command to makefile always. It doesn't matter if exists  `"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/DPSM.FI"` or not. Exactly as I wanted. Could somebody explain this behavior?.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the comments `add_custom_target` is missing. Set your `DEPENDS` right and it will only rerun when the dependencies changed. Its a little bit tricky and hard to remember, so i always consult this [example](https://gist.github.com/socantre/7ee63133a0a3a08f3990). Also check the comments there